# How to get a zipped file from Google Drive using NodeJS googleapis commands?

Tags: node.js, download, google-api, compression, drive

I am trying to use the Google Drive API to store some of those mildly secret files that don't belong in a public git repo. (eg Nginx virtual host config files, a zipped directory tree of database initialization files, etc.) so that I can pull them into a server installation script, when needed.

I have put them there manually and my NodeJs app is able to pull the individual text files without problem. **Unfortunately, that's not the case with compressed files**.

I can drag and drop a zipped file onto the Drive folder and later select it, download it, decompress it and get back to where I was, exactly.  So I know the file itself does survive storage there. No surprise.

My NodeJs app that pulls down test files successfully, looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const { authorize, loadToken } = require('./auth');

const fileId = process.argv[2];
const fileName = process.argv[3];
const targetPath = process.env.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR;


/**
 * Gets a single file from GDrive and writes it to ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}
 * File specified by the command line parameters
 *  - 1st. fileId
 *  - 2nd. fileName
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getFile(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  const options = {encoding:'utf-8', flag:'w'};

  drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    // mimeType: 'application/gzip',
    alt: 'media'
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    process.stdout.write(fileName);
    const filePath = `${targetPath}/${fileName}`;
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, res.data, options);
  });
}

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getFile);
});
```

To show what I am seeing, I created a tiny little `tar.gz`.
Here's what it looks like before uploading to GDrive:

```
me@desktop:~/temp$ ls -la Example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 me us 551 Mar  8 06:53 Example.tar.gz
me@desktop:~/temp$ tar -tf Example.tar.gz 
bottles/
bottles/design/
bottles/design/bottles.json
bottles/bottles_short.json
me@desktop:~/temp$ cat Example.tar.gz; echo "";
�W�\��Qo�0�y���`�Ю�lb��)͞��
9@W��t�"��� P Z�II���������yf�*οZ'����(|O��K����{.��w-����j��QƬ��U�L�K�e����>=M���c9�!,}����������?=���^
                                                                                                                       <������I�����=�3|����ف��o0t��vP{���TL��:PX��R��7٨�ފcZ�=�I�����D1e�2:�޿F��3V���u̦�);�&;��8ѦI�v ~k���oI�,��YG�B(�
���;+Xa��S
          �W
            ޻ڇ��ߏA��6�����BH����������[��ɡy��?�e�����������-���v�\l~���tt3�����>�.E�fv}�WѨ��w����(f�\�K~u�E'k;ס
ap����i�k�u.-�[>�
NAAAAAA��?{��(�?.���_�v��"���g���"�p7���
me@desktop:~/temp$
```

Here's what it looks like after using `googleapis` to download from GDrive:
Notice that it is twice the size on disk, but the stuff from `cat` looks very, very similar.

```
me@server:/run/user/1001$ ls -la Example.tar.gz 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me us 1011 Mar  8 04:39 Example.tar.gz
me@server:/run/user/1001$ tar -tf Example.tar.gz 

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
me@server:/run/user/1001$ cat Example.tar.gz; echo "";
�W�\�Qo�0�y���`�Ю�lb��)͞��
9@W��t�"��� P Z�II���������yf�*οZ'����(|O��K����{.��w-��j��QƬ��U�L�K�e����>=M���c9�!,}���������?=���^
                                                                                                                    <�����I����=�3|����ف��o0t��vP{��TL��0K�*4A���AI�'Yl���,e_�,�`;���(RF��3V���u̦�);�&;��8ѦI�v ~:PX��R��7٨�ފcZ�=�I�����D1e�2:�޿
���;+Xa��S
          �W
            ޻ڇ��ߏA��6����BH����������[��ɡy��?�e����������-���v�\l~���tt3�����>�.E�fv}�WѨ��w����(f�\�K~u�E'k;ס
ap����i�k�u.-�[>�
NAAAAAA��?{��(�?.��_�v��"���g���"�p7���
me@server:/run/user/1001$
```

As you can see from the commented out line, I tried setting `mimeType`.  It made no difference.

I have three questions:

1. Wtf?
2. What can I do to download a GZ file from GDrive?
3. Is there some kind of pre-processing or post-processing or both, that I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Geez.  I guess this is a good example of "if you can't solve a problem just tell it to a wooden indian" **.

Pre- and post-processing is the answer, of course. Duh!

Before pushing out to GDrive:

```
base64 Example.tar.gz > Example.tar.gz.b64
```

After pulling back out of GDrive:

```
base64 -d Example.tar.gz.b64 > Example.tar.gz
```

** In the last millenium, just like barber shops had a red and white spiral "barber pole" outside, tobacconists had a wooden indian. Often, smokers with a nagging problem would be seen pacing in front of the indian, mumbling and gesticulating.  Oddly enough, this was not a bad way of getting the subconscious to work on it.

[Wooden Indian (jpg)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Cigarindian1.jpg/170px-Cigarindian1.jpg)